# Updating Xamarin studio to Visual Studio 2017 code giving error in Xamarin form Android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

After Updating Xamarin studio to Visual Studio 2017 code giving error in Xamarin form Android (IOS code work fine in VS2017) ?

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error MSB4018: The Resolve Library Project Imports task failed unexpectedly.
This is an unhandled exception from a task -- PLEASE OPEN A BUG AGAINST THE TASK OWNER.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Crashlytics.Droid, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Crashlytics.Droid.dll'
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x000c2] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/9dbc4c53/source/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:225 
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (System.String fullName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00001] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/9dbc4c53/source/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:170 
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (System.String fullName) [0x00001] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/9dbc4c53/source/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:165 
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly (System.String fileName) [0x00001] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/9dbc4c53/source/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:160 
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks. Resolve Library Project Imports.Extract (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection1[T] jars, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection1[T] resolvedResourceDirectories, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection1[T] resolvedAssetDirectories, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection1[T] resolvedEnvironments) [0x001f2] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/9dbc4c53/source/xamarin-android/src/Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks/Tasks/Resolve Library ProjectImports .cs:197 
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks. Resolve Library Project Imports.Execute () [0x000e7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/9dbc4c53/source/xamarin-android/src/Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks/Tasks/Resolve Library Project Imports.cs:76 
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute () [0x0002a] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/msbuild-15.0/src/XMakeBuildEngine/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:632 
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+d__26.MoveNext () [0x002bf] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/msbuild-15.0/src/XMakeBuildEngine/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:787 (MSB4018) (DMS-Live.Droid)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: do you use Google Maps? check this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69768/could-not-load-assembly-xamarin-ios-in-an-android-project

Comment: I'm not using Google Maps in app. I have added GCM in my project. is it something related to that?

Comment: try to remove it and see